# Training xgboost with soft labels

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm trying to distill the predictions of another classifier model, "C" using xgboost. Thus, instead of labels, I have the probabilities predicted by C for the samples being positive.

I've tried doing the most obvious thing, using the probabilities output by C as if they were labels

```
distill_model = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=10, n_estimators=100)
distill_model.fit(X, probabilities)
```

but it seems that in that case XGBoost just translates each distinct probability value to its own class. So if C output 72 distinct values, XGBoost considers that as 72 to different classes. I've tried changing the objective function to multi:softmax/multi:softprob but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably an xgboost specific method with custom loss. But a generic solution is to split each training row into two rows one with each label, and assign each row the original probability for that label as its weight.